# Date picker is not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have developed the date picker using Bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery is

```
$(function() {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({minDate:new Date()});
        });
```

Everything works fine but at the end selected date and time is not showing . What is wrong in this

Comment: Open Console window of browser and check for error

Comment: looks like you didn't use `maxDate`

Comment: When instantiating the datepicker on a `div` element you need to handle the selection event yourself, then place the chosen value in the `input` manually.

Comment: do you mean the date and time are not displaying in the input field after selecting date and time from datetimepicker?

Comment: @charankumar yes exactly

Comment: "datetimepicker1" are you sure that this is used only once in the page, if it used two times then it wont display datetime, make sure you have used id only once

Comment: i'm using only one time. I have checked @charankumar

Comment: try <input type="date"

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that will help you

You can view more about datetimepicker from [here](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>datepicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div>Date In TextBox: <input class="form-control" type="text" id="actualDate"></div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Date</label>
        <div class='input-group'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                timepicker: false,
                onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                    $('#actualDate').val($input.val());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @GonnaHack, i update solution for you, may it help you

Comment: u r displaying date other text box , but I want in same box

Comment: Please view updated solution, you assign `id=datetimepicker1` to div thats why its not showing selected datetime you need to assign id to `<input>` element, if it helps then accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Bootstrap 4.1.2. It worked fine in 3. Ended up using HTML5 Date and Time separately and it worked just fine since I didn't want to roll back to Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score -1):

```
 you can use jquery library easily get the date picker  your needs
 see below example

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>datepicker</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   } );
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></div>


</body>
</html>
```